# use "above" to describe something far away

Tags: word-usage

I am aware that the word "above" has lots of meanings, such as

> in or to a higher position than something else;
>
> more than an amount or level;
>
> in a more important or advanced position than someone else.

This post focuses on the first meaning, that is, "a higher position".

The following sentence is meaningful

> It's on the shelf just above your head

since it tells me where is the thing I am looking for.

Technically, the sentence is correct "the bird is **above** the tree", although the bird is a bit far from the tree.

[image]

In real life, are there some situations where I need to use "**above**" to describe something far away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may depend on how far away it is. Since "above" can mean "directly over", it would be confusing if you used it at too great a distance.  For very great distances, you would probably use "higher", or even "at a greater elevation/altitude".

Comment: Thank you. When "above" means "directly over", are "above" and "on top of" interchangeable?

Comment: No, "on top of" is more likely to mean "resting on", that is, in physical contact with. It _can_ mean very near to and above, but that meaning is not as likely.